# How to Compare Information in csv file with Python?

Tags: python, compare, lines

I'm working on a csv file.
I have different columns, each corresponding to an information of my dataset.
Suppose my file contain for each line:

- name information1 information2 information3

-for lines having the same name and information1 and 2 I have to compute the mean for inf3

this is the piece of code where I stopped:

```
col_a=[row[1] for row in file]
for i in col_a:
    currentrow=col_a[1]
    nextrow=col_a[2]
for i in range(0,len(col_a)):
    if (currentrow)==set(nextrow):???
```

I started some months ago to programme, please understand my difficulties.

Comment: read python's csv module

Comment: no, I can read a csv file. I don't know how to compare things.I'll put a piece of code.

Comment: It is not clear from your example what you need. Could you edit your question to include a couple of complete lines from your CSV? One which matches and one which does not.

Comment: You're right..I try to explain better, if the elements in the first col are the same AND also elements for the other cols are the same , I will have to do some statistics on the elements of an other column corresponding to these that are equals

Comment: Is the file sorted?  Do you need to remember past lines?

Comment: yes it is sorted, suppose it contains: name information1 information2 information3                                                                                                    if name is the same and inf1 and inf2 are the same I have to compute the mean for inf3

Comment: Thank you for the comments with additional information.  Can you please edit the question to include them?  SO needs for the question to stand on its own because comments are considered ephemera here.

Answer (score 0):

I am still really struggling to understand what is needed, but here goes. The following script first blocks together groups of rows for which the first column matches, e.g. 3 "aaa" rows.

For each block it locates rows which have matching columns of interest. If two or more are found, the average is calculated on them.

```
import collections

file = [
    ["aaa", "3", "x", "g", "b", 4],
    ["aaa", "4", "e", "r", "t", 3],
    ["aaa", "3", "x", "g", "b", 7],
    ["vv1", "5", "w", "a", "s", 42],
    ["vv2", "5", "w", "a", "s", 10],
    ["vvv", "5", "w", "a", "s", 1],
    ["vvv", "5", "w", "a", "s", 4],
    ["vvv", "5", "w", "a", "s", 3]]

def calculate_stats(block):
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    # Build a dictionary of rows with matching columns
    for cols in block:  
        key = (cols[2], cols[3])        # columns to match e.g. "x" and "g"
        d[key].append(cols)

    for key, rows in d.items():
        if len(rows) > 1:
            col_f = [cols[5] for cols in rows]      # calculate mean on col f
            print "Matched: ", rows, "Mean: ", sum(col_f) / float(len(col_f))

last_row = file[0]
block = []

for cols in file:
    if cols[0] == last_row[0]:
        block.append(cols)
    elif len(block) > 1:
        calculate_stats(block)
        block = [cols]
    else:
        block = []
    last_row = cols

# Deal with any remainder

if len(block) > 1:
    calculate_stats(block)
```

For the sample data I have used, the following results are displayed:

```
Matched:  [['aaa', '3', 'x', 'g', 'b', 4], ['aaa', '3', 'x', 'g', 'b', 7]] Mean:  5.5
Matched:  [['vvv', '5', 'w', 'a', 's', 4], ['vvv', '5', 'w', 'a', 's', 3]] Mean:  3.5
```

Comment: Thanks, you understood perfectly even if I explained not correctly!

Comment: Glad to help, and you found it useful.